# Is there a reference for accessing the Google APIs in a non-OOP way?

Tags: oauth, coldfusion, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api

We are attempting to use the Google APIs to create folders and documents on Google Drive, and provide a link to access them.  This is a relatively simple requirement.  However, all of the reference materials I've found show code examples from a variety of object oriented programming languages that seem to use helper libraries.  We are using ColdFusion, and need to access the API through direct HTTP calls (CFHTTP), for which I can find no good documentation for.

Is there documentation anywhere, from Google or otherwise, showing the URLs and URL variables required for each call?  We would require these for both oAuth2.0 and Google Drive.

Comment: Since you're using coldfusion, you should be able to make use of the java version (though i have little to no experience doing so). Or, you can install another version that you're comfortable with and monitor the requests/responses being made. There doesn't appear to be any documentation of the rest api itself.

Comment: Like this: https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/ ? I googled "google drive rest api", and it was the first link.

Comment: most or all google apis have a "rest" documented way of using it, which is done with raw https calls. certainly the drive docs have it.

Comment: @AdamCameron v1 is deprecated v2 should be used instead: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

Comment: Cheers @abraham: that's a good correction. My point still stands though, I think: Google is rather good at answering "how do I..." sorts of questions when using common technologies.

Comment: @AdamCameron & abraham: This is exactly what I was looking for, and I'm not sure why I didn't see it in my Google searches.  Google does provide a great deal of documentation, but there's so much I often find myself lost in it for hours without finding what I need.  Could you please post https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/ as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just extracting this from some comments.

Google (search term: "[google drive rest api](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=google%20drive%20rest%20api)") turns up an old version of the docs: "[Drive REST API Reference (v1)](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/)". As per @abraham's guidance, the current version is actually this: "[Drive REST API Reference (v2)](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)".

Answer (score 1):

Here @ [Google Drive API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/) you can find all the available APIs. Click on any API, there you get all the variables (required and optional) with description. And there make a request they will show you the requested URL and `json` response.

Also have a look on [this site](https://developers.google.com/drive/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a pitch for using the Java Client library anyway, primarily based on this recommendation from Google:

> Although your application can complete these tasks by directly
>   interacting with the OAuth 2.0 system using HTTP, the mechanics of
>   server-to-server authentication interactions require applications to
>   create and cryptographically sign JSON Web Tokens (JWTs), and it's
>   easy to make serious errors that can have a severe impact on the
>   security of your application.
>
> For this reason, we strongly encourage you to use libraries, such as
>   the Google APIs client libraries, that abstract the cryptography away
>   from your application code.

(Read more [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#callinganapi))

We just went through a similar process getting access to the Google Cloud Storage APIs.

If you do decide to go that route, you'll have to translate the Java code examples to make it ColdFusion friendly.  Here's an example of doing a simple request to the Cloud Storage API (Getting info about one of our Buckets):

```
httpTransport = createObject("java", "com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport").init();
jsonFactory = createObject("java","com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory").init();
credentialBuilder =
createObject("java", "com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder");

credentialBuilder.setTransport(httpTransport);
credentialBuilder.setJsonFactory(jsonFactory);
credentialBuilder.setServiceAccountId("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS");
p12File =createObject("java", "java.io.File").init(expandPath("PATH_TO_P12_FILE"));
credentialBuilder.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12File);
StorageScopes = createObject("java", "com.google.api.services.storage.StorageScopes");

// Alternative StorageScopes: DEVSTORAGE_READ_ONLY, DEVSTORAGE_READ_WRITE
credentialBuilder.setServiceAccountScopes([StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL]);
credential = credentialBuilder.build();

httpRequestInitializer = createObject("java", "com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer");

dataStoreFactory = createObject("java", "com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory").init(DATA_STORE_DIR);

storage = createObject("java", "com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Builder").init(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential);
storage.setApplicationName(APP_NAME);
storage = storage.build();
getBucket = storage.buckets().get(BUCKET_NAME);
getBucket.setProjection("full");
bucket = getBucket.execute();
```